# Bootstrap required validation not working as expected

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm following an online tutorial to add form validation to my Angular app below.
I've followed the steps exactly, and the validation works fine in the tutorial, but not in my code.

Below is the input that I am trying to add validation to:

```
<div class="form-group" [class.hasError]="fullNameControl.invalid">
      <label for="fullName" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
      <input
        required
        id="fullName"
        name="fullName"
        [(ngModel)]="fullName"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        #fullNameControl="ngModel"
      />
      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="fullNameControl.invalid">Full Name is required</span>
</div>
```

When the user leaves the field empty, the Label, perimeter of the input field & the span tag should be in red, but instead they are appearing like this:

[image: validation]

Can someone please help as to why the bootstrap validation isn't working?

Also FYI, bootstrap is working fine in the other parts, so it has been imported correctly.

Comment: What's up with that `#` before `fullNameControl`?

Comment: perhaps `[class.has-error]="fullNameControl.invalid"` would apply valid class and red border will appear